# Visio: How to reverse engineer a database to Crow's Foot Database Notation?

Tags: database, visio

In Visio, how to reverse engineer an existing database to *Crow's Foot Database Notation*? I already have a SQL Server database and I want to reverse engineer some of its tables into a *Crow's Foot Database Notation* Visio diagram. But I cannot find the option to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse engineering feature was removed from Visio starting with Visio 2013 and the feature is no longer available in Visio 2016 and later versions. The Reverse Engineer Wizard is available in Visio Online Plan. and: a  Database Reverse Engineering add-in is available for Visio Pro for Office 365, which allows users to document SQL Server databases and create snapshots of a database at a point in time [ref.](https://www.orbussoftware.com/resources/blog/article/database-reverse-engineering-for-visio-pro) - not sure about crowsfeet though - you will need to research that.

If you have an older Vision try using the Database Model Diagram template.

- Open Visio and select New > Software and Database > Database Model Diagram.
- Choose Metric Units or US Units, and then Create.
- On the Database tab, select Reverse Engineer.
- Follow the steps in the wizard to connect to your database and select the tables you want to include in your diagram.

Once you have created your diagram, set it to display Crow’s Foot via the Database tab and Display Options. On the Relationship tab, select the Crow’s feet check box, and click OK

Comment: Sorry, I want upwote your answer. But I pressed the wrong button.

Comment: Well you could just click the same button to withdraw the down vote

Comment: `You last voted on this answer 4 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.` I get this message when I try withdraw.